# Fractions in fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone please help me step by step through this simplification? How do I get from what's on the LHS to the RHS?

$$\frac{1-\frac{1-x}{1+x}}{1+\frac{1-x}{1+x}} = \frac{1+x-1+x}{1+x+1-x} = x.$$

Many thanks.

Comment: Take common denominator both at the numerator and at the denominator of the left hand side, then observe that the denominators of numerator and denominator cancel.

Comment: Multiply the numerator and denominator of the larger fraction on the LHS by $1 + x$. Note how the $1 + x$ will cancel the denominators from the smaller fractions.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the LHS by $$\frac{1+x}{1+x}$$

to get $$\frac{1-\frac{1-x}{1+x}}{1+\frac{1-x}{1+x}}=
\frac{1-\frac{1-x}{1+x}}{1+\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\cdot \frac{1+x}{1+x}=
\frac{(1+x)1-(1+x)\frac{1-x}{1+x}}{(1+x)1+(1+x)\frac{1-x}{1+x}}=
\frac{1+x-1+x}{1+x+1-x}=
\frac{2x}{2}=x$$

Note that this is valid because an expression times $1$ is the same expression. Another very important thing to note is that this simplification assumes $x\ne -1$, otherwise $\frac{1+x}{1+x}$ is undefined.

Comment: How did you get rid of the (1-x / 1+x) fraction by multiplying it with (1+x)? I still don't get it.

Comment: Hold on, I'll edit my answer to show one more intermediate step. Does this help? The $1+x$ in the numerator cancels with the $1+x$ in the denominator

Comment: I understand that you have to multiply (1+x) with the larger fraction. But I don't get why multiplying (1+x) with ((1-x) / (1+x)) will cancel the denominator. Could you please elaborate these steps a little bit further?

Comment: If you do (1+x) * ((1-x)/(1+x)), doesn't that mean you will have to solve for (1+x)(1-x), which is 1 - x + x - x^2? The -x and + x I can cross out, so I will have ((1 - x^2)/(1+x)). Am I doing something entirely wrong here?

Comment: @David because there is a factor of (1+x) in the numerator and one in the denominator, so they cancel. Its no different than simplifying $\frac{-3\times5}{5}=-3$.

Answer (score 0):

Another simplification of what already has been done:
 $$\frac{1-\frac{1-x}{1+x}}{1+\frac{1-x}{1+x}}=
\frac{\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1-x}{1+x}}{\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1-x}{1+x}}
=\frac{\frac{1(x+1)}{1(x+1)}-\frac{1-x}{1+x}}{\frac{1(x+1)}{1(x+1)}-\frac{1-x}{1+x}}=
\frac{\frac{(x+1)-(1-x)}{1+x}}{\frac{(x+1)+(1-x)}{1+x}}=$$ Where we know that we can rewrite
$$\frac{{(x+1)-(1-x)}}{1+x} \div \frac{{(x+1)+(1-x)}}{1+x}= \frac{(x+1)+(1-x)}{1+x}* \frac{1+x}{(1-x)-(x+1)}$$
Such that
$$\frac{(x+1)-(1-x)}{1+x}* \frac{1+x}{(1-x)+(x+1)}$$

Will allow us to cancel out the $(1+x)$ to finally get 
$$\frac{(1+x)-(1-x)}{(1+x)+(1-x)}=\frac{1+x-1+x}{1+x+1-x}=\frac{2x}{2}=x$$

Hopefully this helps